# List the files on a MTP device

Tags: android, c++, windows, winapi, mtp

It seems that:

```
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(L"mtp://phone/SDcard/music/, &ffd);

if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        //...
    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

doesn't work for devices connected via MTP. Is there a WinAPI function for this?

More precisely: how to list all the filenames (+filesize and modification date) on a device connected to PC via MTP (such as Android phone), in C/C++?

Comment: One way is with the [Windows Portable Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389005(v=vs.85).aspx) API although it's not a particularly friendly API. You can also use the shell interfaces to enumerate the appropriate parts of the shell namespace.